# Sparse Principal Component Analysis using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca

I'm trying to replicate an application from this [paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Pubs/SPCAhandbookSV.pdf), where the authors download the [20 newsgroups](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html) data and use SPCA to extract the principal components that in some sense best describe the text corpus [see section 4.1]. This is for a high dimensions class project where we were asked to pick a topic and replicate/apply it.

The output should be K principal components, which each have a short list of words that all intuitively correspond to a certain theme (for example, the paper finds the first PC is all about politics and religion).

From my research it seems like the best way to reproduce the application from this paper is using this algorithm: `sklearn.decomposition.MiniBatchSparsePCA`.

I have found only one example of how this alogrithm works, [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_faces_decomposition.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-faces-decomposition-py).

So my question is this: Is it, in principal, possible to follow the steps in the above linked example, using text data to reproduce the application from section 4.1 in the paper linked in the first paragraph?

If it is, I would then be able to ask more concrete question regarding the code.

Comment: These are way too many questions and it feels unclear what you are trying to do and what fails on many ends. (0) That paper is introducing algorithms to solve the SPCA problem. Instead of implementing, you want to take another algorithm (from sklearn). That's not really reproducing the paper, right? (1) A sparse-matrix is just a lossless form of storage. For original-data or other-data, there will be dense and sparse storage-schemes. Tried and failed is useless if you don't describe what the problem is. (2) sklearn's docs are the best i know. You link the API-docs. Read the tutorials too.

Comment: Ok. Then just grab the linked data, read it in and fit sklearns SparsePCA or MiniBatchSparsePCA. They are just taking this binary dense vec of size 100 as input, so you can too.

Comment: @sascha, thanks for your comment. I have made substantial changes to the question, which hopefully clarifes things a little. I realise this is now more or less a yes/no question, so depending on the correct etiquette I may ask a new question when I have more concrete coding related questions. I searched again for tutorial docs, but found only this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/index.html), which has lots of text data material, but as mentioned above, I'm not sure how relevant that is to this application.

Comment: There is no real question here besides: how to replicate it. Where is the problem: read the data [using scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html#scipy.io.loadmat); fit; read out components. Those steps are outlined in the paper. And everything else is just doc-reading. The only other thing is how to compute the *explained variance*. Does not seem to be supported out of the box for this function. But maybe you can learn from the implementation of the classic PCA alg which does that.

Comment: So yes. You can do those experiments too. But be careful with things like [this note in the tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#sparse-principal-components-analysis-sparsepca-and-minibatchsparsepca): ```Note that there are many different formulations for the Sparse PCA problem. The one implemented here is based on [Mrl09]```

Comment: Agree there is no real question now- but great to get confirmation that this is possible. I know that's obvious to you, but I'm on a steep learning curve. Appreciate the clarifications and I will look into how classic PCA deals with explained variance. Cheers, S.