# MiniBatchSparsePCA on Text Data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-mining, pca, sklearn-pandas

**Goal**

I'm trying to replicate an application described in this [paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Pubs/SPCAhandbookSV.pdf) (section 4.1), where Sparse Principal Component Analysis is applied to a text corpus with the output being K principal components, each displaying a 'structure that is otherwise hidden'. In other words, the principal components should each contain a list of words, all of which share a common theme.

I have used sklearn's MiniBatchSparsePCA package to try to replicate the application, though my output is a matrix of zeros.

**Data**
My data comes from a survey which was cleaned in Stata. It is a vector of 386 answers; which are sentences.

**My Attempt**

```
# IMPORT LIBRARIES #
####################################
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
####################################

# USE SKLEARN TO IMPORT STATA DATA. #
# Data comes from a survey, which was cleaned using Stata.

####################################
data_source = "/Users/****/q19_free_text.dta"
raw_data = pd.read_stata(data_source) #Reading in the data from a Stata file.  
text_data = raw_data.iloc[:,1] #Cleaning out Observation ID number.
text_data.shape     # Out[268]: (368, ) - There are 368 text (sentence) answers.
####################################

# Term Frequency – Inverse Document- Word Frequency
####################################
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(text_data)

spca = decomposition.MiniBatchSparsePCA(n_components=2, alpha=0.5)
spca.fit(X_train) 
#TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

X_train2 = X_train.toarray() #Trying with a dense array...
spca.fit(X_train2)

components = spca.components_


print(components)  #Out: [[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
                   #     [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]

components.shape   #Out: (2, 916)

# Empty output!
```

**Other Notes**

I used these sources to write the above code:

[Official Example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_faces_decomposition.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-faces-decomposition-py)

[Vectorising Text data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html)

[Previous question on the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906412/sparse-principal-component-analysis-using-sklearn)

Comment: Did you try smaller `alpha`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When I reduce alpha by a factor of 100 (arbitrarily), I do get non-zero output for some of my components. However I've been unable to transform these numbers back into features, like the paper linked above does. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what 'transform these numbers back into features' means.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. As mentioned in the question, my goal is to do something similar to that which is done in section 4.1 in the paper linked. There they 'summarize' a text corpus by using SPCA and the output is K components, where each component is a list of words (or, features). Hope that clarifies! Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (...) to do something similar to that which is done in section 4.1 in the paper linked. There they 'summarize' a text corpus by using SPCA and the output is K components, where each component is a list of words (or, features).

If I understand you correctly, you ask how to retrieve words for the components.

You can do this by retrieving indices of nonzero entries in components (use appropriate `numpy` code on `components`). Then using `vectorizer.vocabulary_` you can find out which indices (words/tokens) are found in your components.

See [this notebook](https://github.com/lambdaofgod/stackexchange/blob/master/stackoverflow/SPCA%20Word%20Clusters.ipynb) for an example implementation (I used 20 newsgroups dataset).

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding. This is exactly what I was looking for- many thanks! I have been playing around with the parameters however and I was wondering if you would be able to offer any clarifications. Based on my reading I had thought that batch_size and n_iter would affect performance rather than the output, but having changed their values that doesn't seem to be the case. Does this make sense? How should those parameters be chosen? Likewise for alpha, which I believe is the weighing assigned to the Lasso Vs Elastic net (i.e. the relative importance of the L1 & L2 norms)

Comment: 'How should those parameters be chosen' - it depends on what you want to enforce on the model. For example if you set it too low there will be lots of nonzero components so it won't be so simple to describe topics.

Comment: BTW Elasticnet is weighted combination of L2 and L1 regularization. You can read SPCA's documentation on what parameters can be tuned and what do they mean.

Comment: Apologies, of course you're right. I should have said EN is a combination of Lasso & Ridge. I actually had a fairly in-depth look at the SPCA docs, but didn't manage to get a great grasp of how I should expect my output to change, given certain parameter changes. But perhaps a little trial and error wouldn't go amiss. Thanks again for all your help & generosity of time!